# SnakeYAML loads Objects that cannot be used conventionally

Tags: java, object, compiler-errors, primitive, snakeyaml

So I am loading a YAML file using this code.

```
String file = "A: true\nB: 5"
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
Map settings = (Map) yaml.load(file);

System.out.println(settings.get("A"));
```

The last line prints this:

```
class    java.lang.Boolean
```

which is expected.  However, when I try to actually use the Boolean, for example with a basic if-statement:

```
if (settings.get("A")) {
    System.out.println("We want to do A!");
}
```

this statement throws an error:

```
java: incompatible types
    required: boolean
    found:    java.lang.Object
```

telling me that the if-statement was expecting a boolean but received a java.lang.Object instead. This has me confused.  Why, when I get the objects class, does it return the type that I want, but that object cannot be used in the context of said type?

At first, I naively thought it might be the fact that SnakeYAML was returning a subclass of Object type rather than a primitive type.  After some tests and a small amount of thought, I realized that was no the cause of my issue.

I realized that I can fix this error by simply casting each value as its respective type, but my YAML file contains a lot of different values which I don't want to manually cast each time I reference them... that somewhat defeats my purpose for using YAML in the first place.

Anyway, insight into why I can't use an object that thinks its a Boolean **as a boolean** would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure java issue.

```
Map settings = new HashMap();
if (settings.get("A")) {
    System.out.println();
}
```

will give you the same compiler error for the same reason - Map (without type templates) have Object keys and Object values.

However, using type templates will not help in your case, since there is no way of knowing the type of the value at compile time. Think about it: If you change the input to "A: hello\nB: 5", the runtime type of settings.get("A") would be java.lang.String.

So, you will have to stick with your explicit cast and get a ClassCastException if you change the input to a non-boolean value.